# How to use a return value from a gtest to another test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I am trying to test a C++ program via Google test framework.

**My code:**

```
int addNumbers(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int subtractNumbers(int a, int b)
{
    return a - b;
}
```

**Unit test Code:**

```
//first test
TEST(testMath, addTest1)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(37, addNumbers(14, 23));
    getchar();
}

//second test
TEST(testMath, subtractTest1)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(25, subtractNumbers(37, 12));
    getchar();
}

//third test
TEST(testMath, addTest2)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(62, addNumbers(37, 25));
    getchar();
}
```

But, I need my unit test to be in a different way.

**My Expectation:** I need to get the return value (result) of the first test and use it in the second test as dynamic (If the first test is failed, then the program should terminate showing error details). When the first test and the second test are OK (not failed), then the return values from the first and second test should be parameterized to the third test.

**Desired Algorithm (as help from you):**

Step 1: Run first test `addNumbers(14, 23)`;

Step 2: Check the expected and return values(A);

Step 3.1: If test failed, terminate the program showing Error details;

Step 3.2: If OK (not failed), Run the second test `subtractNumbers(A, 12)`;

Step 4: Check the expected and return values(B);

Step 5.1: If test failed, terminate the program showing OK details and Error details;

Step 5.2: If OK (not failed), Run the third test `addNumbers(A,B)`;

Step 6: Check the expected and return values;

Step 7.1: If test failed, terminate the program showing OK details and Error details;

Step 7.2: If OK, show the OK details.

Comment: Why do you want to stop test at first error ? As the tests should be independent, having all failing tests allow to fix several at once. It is the same as compilation, having all errors is better that stopping at the first IMO.

Comment: [OT]: you should not use `getchar()` in test, use *breakpoint* if you want to "pause" execution for debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the various `ASSERT_*` macros will cause a test to abort on failure. You can convert the `EXPECT_EQ` to `ASSERT_EQ`, then place them all within the same `TEST()`.

```
TEST(testMath, testAll)
{
  auto A = addNumbers(14, 23);
  ASSERT_EQ(37, A);
  auto B = subtractNumbers(A, 12)
  ASSERT_EQ(25, B);
  ASSERT_EQ(62, addNumbers(A, B));
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to parameterise the second test as static. I want it to be dynamic. For eg: `ASSERT_EQ(25, subtractNumbers(first_test_result, 12));` or something like that.

Comment: Could help me at this part in the answer?

Comment: @MohammedShereif Why don't you just use `auto result = addNumbers(14, 23); ASSERT_EQ(37, result);` and so forth?

Comment: @MohammedShereif Updated the answer to reflect the refined question.

Comment: I could do that, but I am in a research on elaborating the knowledge in google test framework. So basically, if gtest provides the answer to my question without other statements, then why not.